# Target P inside class using Javascript .getElement

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code inside my slider. It works with a CMS so i need to use javascript to reach the first and second p inside that slide. So i can add the classes: mx-auto and text-truncate to those p's. 
But i have not been able to get the code to insert those classes into the p's.

Just to make it clear about why i am not able to just add the classes manually. The CMS adds the P programmatically so im unable to change that.

I have used bootstrap's 4.0 as my slider.

```html
<div class="carousel-item">

  <img class="d-block w-100" src="/Nieuwbouw/upload/images/banner1_1.png" alt="House 1">
  <div class="carousel-caption mx-auto d-none d-md-block">
    <h3 class="mx-auto">This is the title</h3>
    <span class="caption-text1">
      <p>This is the subtitel <-- TARGET THIS --></p>

    </span>
    <span class="caption-text2">
      <p>This is all text! <-- AND THIS --></p>

    </span>
    <h3 class="mx-auto">From €256.000,-</h3>
    <a href="#">+ see more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many variaties of the below code but got nothing to work (did not insert the classes)

```
var targetElement1 = document.getElementsByClassName(".caption-text1").getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
targetElement1.classList.add('mx-auto', 'text-truncate');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way by using `querySelectorAll`:

```js
var pElement = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item span > p');
pElement.forEach(function(p){
 p.setAttribute('class','mx-auto text-truncate');
 console.log(p);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-item">

  <img class="d-block w-100" src="/Nieuwbouw/upload/images/banner1_1.png" alt="House 1">
  <div class="carousel-caption mx-auto d-none d-md-block">
    <h3 class="mx-auto">This is the title</h3>
    <span class="caption-text1">
      <p>This is the subtitel <-- TARGET THIS --></p>

    </span>
    <span class="caption-text2">
      <p>This is all text! <-- AND THIS --></p>

    </span>
    <h3 class="mx-auto">From €256.000,-</h3>
    <a href="#">+ see more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tweaked your code to my liking :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am missing something - but you can definitely target those elements using document.querySelectorAll (but there are also other ways of getting them too) - I have added the two classes you are trying to - and also a "red" class to demonstrate that the elements have been affected and will now display as red.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item span p');

for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){ 
  elements[i].classList.add('mx-auto','text-truncate','red');
  }
```

```css
.red {color:red}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item">

  <img class="d-block w-100" src="/Nieuwbouw/upload/images/banner1_1.png" alt="House 1">
  <div class="carousel-caption mx-auto d-none d-md-block">
    <h3 class="mx-auto">This is the title</h3>
    <span class="caption-text1">
      <p>This is the subtitel</p>

    </span>
    <span class="caption-text2">
      <p>This is all text!</p>

    </span>
    <h3 class="mx-auto">From €256.000,-</h3>
    <a href="#">+ see more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```